# MySQL merging two queries

Tags: sql, mysql

I have the following table setup:

branches table:

```
...
manager_id
sales_manager_id
admin_manager_id
...
```

the above-mentioned columns contain the foreign key for the users table.

to complicate things I also have a branches_extra table:

branches_extra:

```
id
branch_id
user_id
position_id
```

which contains user_id, branch_id foreign keys for additional, staff that will be displayed on a branches contact page on a website. The porblem is that users are sometimes displayed more than once becuae they can have multiple positions/roles, I currently have 2 queries I am using to return the managers specified in the branches table and then the extra staff in the branches_extra table:

```
SELECT CONCAT( xoops_users_extra.first_name, ' ', xoops_users_extra.last_name ) AS full_name, , xoops_users_extra.profile_image_thumb, xoops_users.email,
            CASE xoops_users_extra.main_userid
                WHEN branches.manager_id THEN 'Manager'
                WHEN branches.sales_manager_id  THEN 'Sales Manager'
                WHEN branches.admin_manager_id  THEN 'Admin Manager'
                WHEN branches.ops_manager_id  THEN 'Ops Manager'
                WHEN branches.export_manager_id  THEN 'Export Manager'
                WHEN branches.import_manager_id  THEN 'Import Manager'
            END AS position,
            CASE xoops_users_extra.main_userid
                WHEN branches.manager_id THEN 1
                WHEN branches.sales_manager_id  THEN 2
                WHEN branches.admin_manager_id  THEN 3
                WHEN branches.ops_manager_id  THEN 4
                WHEN branches.export_manager_id  THEN 5
                WHEN branches.import_manager_id  THEN 6
            END AS sort_order
        FROM (branches, xoops_users_extra, xoops_users)
        WHERE ((branches.manager_id = xoops_users_extra.main_userid)
            OR (branches.sales_manager_id = xoops_users_extra.main_userid)
            OR (branches.admin_manager_id = xoops_users_extra.main_userid)
            OR (branches.ops_manager_id = xoops_users_extra.main_userid)
            OR (branches.export_manager_id = xoops_users_extra.main_userid)
            OR (branches.import_manager_id = xoops_users_extra.main_userid))
            AND xoops_users.uid = xoops_users_extra.main_userid 
            AND branches.branch_id = %d ORDER BY sort_order ASC
```

and for the extra staff:

```
 SELECT CONCAT( xoops_users_extra.first_name, ' ', xoops_users_extra.last_name ) AS full_name, 
        positions.description AS position, xoops_users.email, xoops_users_extra.profile_image_thumb AS thumbnail
    FROM (xoops_users, xoops_users_extra, branches_extra, branches, positions)
    WHERE branches_extra.uid = xoops_users_extra.main_userid
        AND positions.id = branches_extra.position
        AND branches.branch_id = branches_extra.branch_id
        AND xoops_users.uid = xoops_users_extra.main_userid
        AND branches_extra.display =1
        AND branches.branch_id = %d
```

I would like to merge the queries in to a single query and concat the "position" column instead of having multiple entries...

Comment: The overall schema is unclear.  For example What is this main_userid field of the xoops_users_extra table?   What are the positions' table fields etc.   BTW I encourage you to use `explicit JOIN syntax`, because, if nothing else, such constructs introduce "self-documentation", making it much easier to share (or even to revisit, over time) the query source code.

Comment: It's an incomprehensable mess i have recenlty been employed to maintain ;-p

Comment: nevermind i think i will do some array munging in php...

Answer (score 1):

What you probably wanted was [GROUP_CONCAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat)()

```
SELECT userid, GROUP_CONCAT(position SEPARATOR ', ') 
FROM (
   ... position joining.
) 
GROUP BY userid;
```

And use that query as a subquery inside of the larger query.

Comment: You sent me down the right path with GROUP_CONCAT() but I am having trouble trying to get it to accept 'position' as a field, I  getthis error:

#1054 - Unknown column 'position' in 'field list'

I suspect it is because 'position' is not really a column